# How to Relink a Linked Object?

Tags: workflow, blend-files, scene, linked-data

I have to replace a linked object with another one but it would be nice to keep all object transformations of the old proxy.

What is the common way to do this?

Comment: What about adding your other object, then copying the first objects transforms with RMB > copy to selected?

Comment: Thanks gandalf. For me it sounds like a workaround, it whould be nice to edit the path of the linked object instead of placing a new object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select all objects that share linked data, then select your new object last so that it is the active object. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> and select `Object Data` from the menu.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]