# If a blend is saved with missing linked libraries, is that data now permanently lost?

Tags: blend-files, linked-data

Lets say I have an asset named "*John.blend*" that I link into my animation "*Shot_005.blend*".

I animate my awesome character, John, over several days and am eventually happy with it.

[image: John]

Unknown to me, someone renames "*John.blend*" to "*John_FINAL_v1_USETHISONE.blend*".

A while later, I open up my "*Shot_005.blend*" file (without noticing the warnings about the missing library, "*John.blend*", or the empty space in the scene) and make some tweaks to the render settings. I then save the file and close Blender.

The next time I open *Shot_005.blend*, I notice that John has mysteriously vanished, leaving behind only a ghostly Empty object in his place.

[image: Not John]

I then realize that the John file was renamed, and attempt to solve my problem by renaming the file back to "*John.blend*", however upon reloading the shot file, John is still gone (because the library data block no longer exists)

---

Is there any way I can recover my awesome animation that I spent several days on?

Comment: That's a general problem of linking. Same issue here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16359/how-to-relink-a-linked-object. It seems not to be  possible to edit the path of the linked object at the moment. In the other post Gandalf3 suggested to add your lost object, then copy the empty transformations and apply it to the new one.

Comment: i had the same problem when i renamed some folder with dependencies in it. after asking around in #blender irc, i came to see that there is no apparent solution. i could solve it by undoing my renaming of said folder and digging out an older version of the file in one of my backups. that worked. another solution is, as suggested, relink your objects manually and apply the transforms of the now-empties. btw the devs in #blendercoders told me it's a known issue and will be fixed eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no solution, but this will be fixed soon, I think. Remember you can open a backup by opening your FILE.blend1, if its the first wrong save or .blend2, if its the second time, you saved it after your mistake. just activate the Failsave Filter ([image: Failsave]) in the Blender Filebrowser to open your Backup File.